# Read Specific textfile in streamreader

Tags: c#, streamreader

I want to read many delimited files from a folder. However, the calling in the code is per one textfile only.

```
System.IO.StreamReader file =new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Orders\OrdersForImport.txt");
```

I want the "OrdersForImport.txt" to be change.

my textfiles are OrdersForImport, OrdersForImport1, OrdersForImport2, OrdersForImport3, etc.

it is constant that the ".txt" extention will not be change. only the filenames will be change

Comment: You need to use a loop and string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all answer,

here is what I done to read all delimited files in a folder.

> FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
>
> fileSystemWatcher.Path = @"C:\Orders\";
>
> string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fileSystemWatcher.Path, "*.txt");
>
> System.IO.StreamReader files = new System.IO.StreamReader(dir);

PS> I tried all your answers

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to run a loop and read all of them then ...

You could do something like

```
var name_array = "name1.name2.name3".Split(".");
```

and then look and same the input like

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var entry in name_array)
{
   var name = entry +".txt";
   // read your file here giving the `name` to the streamreader 
}
```

Hard to say more without more input though

Answer (score 0):

Split the concatenated file name list and repeat on each of the items:

```
string delimitedNames = "OrdersForImport, OrdersForImport1, OrdersForImport2, OrdersForImport3";
foreach ( string fileName in delimitedNames.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) )
{
     using ( System.IO.StreamReader file =new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Orders\" + fileName.Trim() + ".txt") )
     {
          // do your stuff here
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] Files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Orders");
foreach (string _file in Files)
{
string fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(_file);
//Do something with fileContent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below snippet

```
DirectoryInfo drInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Orders\");
var files = drInfo.GetFiles("OrdersForImport*.txt");
foreach (var item in files)
{
    string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(item.FullName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put all wanted txt files into the same folder (In this case should be here **C:\Orders**), then code to search all txt files as the following code

```
string folderPath = @"C:\Orders\";
string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string filename in filenames)
 {
     using(System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename))
     {
         //handle data from text file here
     }
 }
```